# Fetch parent record field value from Flow get records element

Tags: visual-workflow

I already have a Get Records element to fetch Case and I am trying to display Contact Name on my Flow (this is the standard Contact field on Case).

Is it possible to get the value in the Case.Contact.Name field by not querying the Contact table as well?

What I have tried:

Have tried fetching the value from the get record element itself (default option selected: Automatically store all fields).
Used a formula - didn't work - empty value

Then I chose 'Choose fields and let Salesforce do the rest'.
I can not navigate to the Contact.Name (Enter a valid value)

And thereafter 'Choose fields and assign variables (advanced)' - tried both options for Where to Store Field Values:
Together in a record variable
or In separate variables

Outcome is the same, either I can not reach the variable by dot operator (Contact.Name -- Enter a valid value)
or if I use a formula: I can navigate to the value, but nothing is displayed.

Is it at all possible? I wish to avoid a query and I wish to avoid creating a formula field on the Case object itself.

Edit: I read this and what I want seems possible even with veryy old versions of Visual Workflow, then what am I missing here? https://explorationsintosalesforce.wordpress.com/2015/10/21/cross-object-field-referencing-in-visual-flow/

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I was wrongly using the Contact.Name field. Although Contact.Name works perfectly fine from SOQL, it doesn't in Flow. I changed it to Contact.Firstname & Contact.Lastname and immediately it worked-without using any special changes in get record element, thus the "Automatically store all fields" ..