# Choose Parent Field in Flow Get Records

Tags: visual-workflow, queries

Is there a way I can select `Choose fields and let Salesforce do the rest` or `Choose fields and assign variables (advanced)` in a flow  `Get Records` element, including parent fields?

As I can see [here](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/361708/fetch-parent-record-field-value-from-flow-get-records-element) the only workaround to get such valus `Automatically store all fields` but I would like to avoid it if possible for the sake of performance.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this can be done. Simply include the lookup fields in your *Choose fields* list

For example, if the Flow were fetching a `Contact`, select the `AccountId` field

Then, the rest of your flow will have access to the parent fields.

Here's an example of a `Get Records` element called `Get_Contact`:

[image]
[image]